# Spring Boot Integration test error io.zonky.test.db.provider.ProviderException: Unexpected error when preparing a database cluster only on Pipeline

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-boot-test

Facing the following error

```
Caused by: io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: io.zonky.test.db.provider.ProviderException: Unexpected error when preparing a database cluster
    at io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.wrapAndThrowUnchecked(Futures.java:1546)
    at io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.getUnchecked(Futures.java:1532)
    at io.zonky.test.db.context.DefaultDatabaseContext.awaitDatabase(DefaultDatabaseContext.java:282)
    at io.zonky.test.db.context.DefaultDatabaseContext.getDatabase(DefaultDatabaseContext.java:126)
    at io.zonky.test.db.context.DatabaseTargetSource.getTarget(DatabaseTargetSource.java:32)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:229)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy153.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:160)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:118)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:336)
    at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromMetaData(DatabaseType.java:86)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.DefaultBatchConfiguration.getDatabaseType(DefaultBatchConfiguration.java:396)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.DefaultBatchConfiguration.jobRepository(DefaultBatchConfiguration.java:134)
    ... 94 common frames omitted
```

on Jenkins pipeline, even though it's working fine locally !

Here are the dependency I am using

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.zonky.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>embedded-database-spring-test</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.zonky.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>embedded-postgres</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.6</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```